# extjs 6 grid custom header

Tags: extjs, extjs6

In my ExtJs 6 app I have a grid in which I need to create a custom header. The header, including the column, should have below the columns an extra pair of rows that should be expandable (toggle on/toggle off)

Is there a mechanism in extjs 6 by which I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a multi-line header by nesting multiple columns:

```
columns:[{
    text:'Top header',
    columns:[{
        text:'Middle header',
        columns:[{
            text:'Inner header'
        }]
```

Any of these headers you can modify by deriving from an existing `Ext.grid.column.Column`. The `renderTpl` property of the overridden class can take a custom `XTemplate`. Not sure what exactly you mean with "expandable", but whatever it is, a well-crafted `XTemplate` will be able to handle it.

Comment: By exandable, in this case I mean when you click a toggle button, the nested columns in this case should expand/collapse. Thanks, I will manage from here as this is a good starting point